# Detect windows activities that embed into a AutoGUI by _WinAPI_SetParent

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, autoit

I used `_WinAPI_SetParent` to embed some programs into a **AutoIt GUI** . Then I found I can't detect those program windows anymore, only their parent ( = AutoIt GUI) can be detect. I use ShellHook and it tell me that the program windows are destroyed. Furthermore, ShellHook can't no long detect these program windows neither.

So how to monitor these program windows activities that embedd into a AutoIt GUI, like one can use `WinExists`, `WinActive` and send commands to them, like `WinActivate`, `WinGetHandle`. Or using ShellHook to do this?

This function use   `DllCall("user32.dll", "hwnd", "SetParent", "hwnd", $hWndChild, "hwnd", $hWndParent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once embedded, the windows become controls. As a result, try using the `Control*` functions. For example you'd use `ControlFocus` to replace `WinActivate`, `ControlGetHandle` to replace `WinGetHandle`.

Also, keep the handle and then some windows functions will still work on them. The only difference between windows and controls is that one has a parent window.